# Insert Core Data models from json

Tags: ios, json, xcode, performance, core-data

I have a service to obtain employees that response with the following json:

```
[{ "initials": "PR", "name": "Paul", "accounts": ["SPA", "ITA"] },  
{ "initials": "SR", "name": "William", "accounts": ["ITA"] } ]
```

and another service to obtain accounts that results in a json like this:

```
[{ "code": "SPA", "name": "Spain", "employees": ["PR"]  },
 { "code": "ITA", "name": "Italy", "employees": ["PR", "SR"]  } ]
```

I need to parse and insert the information received into a Core-Data database with two Core Data Models, Employee and Account with a relationship of many-to-many declared. They are declared as follows:

```
@interface Employee : NSManagedObject

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *initials;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *accounts;

@end

@interface Account : NSManagedObject

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *code;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *employees;

@end
```

What I'm doing now it's to insert first the employees, and after create each account and query the employees to insert in each account. Obviously the performance of this is very bad as I need to do a request for each account.

```
- (void)loadEmployeesJSON { ... }
- (void)loadAccountsJSON {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Accounts" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray *accounts = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath] options:kNilOptions error:&err];

    [accounts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        Account *account = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        account.code = [obj objectForKey:@"code"];
        account.name = [obj objectForKey:@"name"];
        account.employees = [self accountsForEmployee:[obj objectForKey:@"employees"]];
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}

- (NSSet*)accountsForEmployee:(NSArray*)initialsArray {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"initials IN %@", initialsArray]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return [NSSet setWithArray:fetchedObjects];
}
```

How could I link them without requesting the employees for each account?
I thought that I can have mapped in memory all the employees and ask for them. But what if my database of employees is too big (+100.000) to have it in memory?

Comment: A better approach for you might be to not use the many-to-many relationships, but instead just have a read-only accounts (and employees) property that you create lazily on reference.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach.  It defeats the point of using Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

You can have all of the employees in memory no matter how big the size.  To do this, after you create the employee entity and save it (in batches preferably), reset them back to faults via:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ...;
NSManagedObject *employee = ...;
[moc refreshObject:employee mergeChanges:NO];
```

By calling `-refreshObject:mergeChanges:` after the save, it will drop the attributes and relationships for that object out of memory and reduce its memory footprint to near zero.  From there you can store it in a `NSDictionary` for later relationship mapping.

This will avoid all of the fetching and dramatically improve your import performance.

Comment: Do you mean add the employee `NSManagedObject` to a `NSMutableDictionary` (using what as key) or convert the employee to a `NSDictionary` and store in an array?

Comment: add the `NSManagedObject` to the dictionary.  Use whatever unique ID you are using in the JSON as your key.  Then when you link up accounts you can use that same unique to process the relationships.